# My awk script don't print 0 and NR with 0

Tags: awk, data-processing

This is my script. How to force my script to print also zero. It is very important to me. I don,t know why it is not print zero, I add a+0, so it should!

```
#!/bin/bash
awk 'a=$1/617 {print NR " " a+0}' sum.txt | tee autocor.txt
```

This is my input

```
1
0
0
1
0
0
0
0
1
```

and this is my output

```
1 0.00162075
4 0.00162075
9 0.00162075
```

Expected output

```
1 0.00162075
2 0
3 0
4 0.00162075
5 0
6 0
7 0
8 0
9 0.00162075
```

Comment: It looks like when `a=$1/617` is used as a condition and `$1` is `0` then the condition is `a=0` which evaluates to `0` which is false. Does `awk '{a=$1/617; print NR " " a+0}'` work?

Comment: Yes, it works! Oh I probably know why It didnt work, I put this in pattern part, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `a = $1 / 617` condition will not be fulfilled when `$1 == 0` (because this value is considered falsy in `awk`). If you want to print every result just do not add any condition to your rule:

```sh
cat input | awk '{ print NR " " $1/617 }'
```

Will print

```
1 0.00162075
2 0
3 0
4 0.00162075
5 0
6 0
7 0
8 0
9 0.00162075
```